# If I'm conducting a matched study with multiple levels (e.g., students within classrooms), what is the appropriate level to match on?

Tags: experiment-design, multilevel-analysis, matching

Let's say that I'm conducting a non-randomized matching evaluating of an educational intervention to determine its impact on student grades. While the students receive the intervention, the teachers are the ones who are trained to administer the intervention, they deliver the intervention, and the effects of the intervention depend in part on how well they implement it. Because I'm interested in the effects of the intervention on individual student outcomes, I'm going to use a multi-level model where students are nested within classrooms. The question is how I should match my treatment students to my control students. **Should I match individual students to one another, because they are the ones receiving the intervention? Or should I match teachers to one another, because they are the ones administering the intervention?**

Comment: Is there a reason you're matching?  My understanding is that the matching is meant to make the distribution of confounders similar between treatment and control, but if you've drawn a DAG and have an identification strategy, then regression should be sufficient.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Regression and propensity score serve the same purpose and are equally valid under the assumption of no unmeasured confounders. The same identify strategy that justifies regression justifies propensity scores.

Comment: I'm not sure what a DAG is to be honest, but you're correct that the goal of matching is to achieve balance on confounders across groups

Comment: +1 for making me think harder about this, though. I think you're right that if I'm modeling confounders in a regression, I don't necessarily need to additionally match on them